# Nodejs - MongoDB findone with exact match but case insensitive

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
db.collection("accounts").findOne({Nickname: { $regex : new RegExp(player, "i") }}, function(err, result) { }
```

Is what I currently have, the problem is that I get everything that is a substring of the player variable. But I want only exact, albeit case-insensitive matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefix `player` with ^ and suffix with $, so that it matches the entire string

`"^" + player + "$"`

^ matches the start of the string

$ matches the end of the string

Reference for [boundary regex characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#boundaries)

So with this expression you're saying "find me Nickname which starts and ends with this string" i.e. the entire string

Answer (score 5):

Your regex actually asks for a substring. To ask for an exact string:

```
new RegExp("^" + player + "$", "i")
```

(Keep everything else the same.)

The `^` matches the beginning of the input, the `$` matches the end. This way, any substrings won't match.